# include stylesheet only for desktop browsers

Tags: css

I can include the stylesheet for different resolutions like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="min800.css" />
```

But I want to include my stylesheet only for desktop browsers not iPad, iOS, mobile browsers.

How can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a feature detection library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check for touch events.

Can't you simply look at the User Agent? I know it can be overridden but it should still work pretty well. Check out [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) for some ideas.

**Edit**

From the comments:

> Hi! Thanks for the link detect mobile browsers. I'll use this. But this is only checking for mobile devices not tablets like iPad. So, how can I modify? I'm using php version.

The iPad user agent looks like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10
```

So find the part of the Regex that looks like this:

```
ip(hone|od)
```

And change it to this:

```
ip(hone|od|ad)
```

Alternatively you can get Modernizr to detect iPad as well with a custom test like this:

```
Modernizr.addTest('ipad', function () {
  return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
});
```

Or you could use a plugin like [Detectizr](https://github.com/barisaydinoglu/Detectizr) that does the hard work for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the link detect mobile browsers. I'll use this. But this is only checking for mobile devices not tablets like iPad. So, how can I modify? I'm using php version.

Comment: You can just add their user agent string as part of the filter. It technically doesn't matter where you put it, although it's generally a good idea to keep them in alphabetical order. So it'd look like this: android|blackberry|**youruseragenthere**|zebra